# how to stub an async handler using sinon

Tags: javascript, lambda, sinon

I'm trying to write dome mocks for my async lambda but I'm getting an error 'TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property account'. Any ideas how to get around it? thanks in advance.

---- test

```
import { handler } from 'handler'

describe('tests', function() {

const sbox = sandbox.create()

describe('a payload is sent', () => {
    it('should return a 200', (done) => {

        const thePayload = thedata;

        sbox.stub(handler, 'handler').resolves(thePayload)

        account(context, context, (err, resp) => {
            expect(resp.statusCode).to.eq(200)
            done()
        })
    })
  })
})
```

---- handler

```
export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

return callback(null, { statusCode: 200 } )

}
```

Comment: In the test file, what are `account()` and `context`? They aren't defined anywhere. I think `account()` is meant to be `handler()`?

Comment: It looks like you're importing only the handler function inside of the handler module.  I think that code expects handler to have a handler property on it, like `handler.handler`.  What if you tried to require the module and then passed that into the stub?  My thinking is that the module would have the handler function exported and would be mockable.  There are probably many ways to fix it, but that's my initial thought.